# How to make basic ruby interpreter

Tags: ruby

This is the basic structure that it should respond to but I don't know how to code the class Interprete

```
 interpreta=Interprete.new

interprete.add("a=0")

interprete.add("b=1")

interprete.add("a=b+10")

interprete.execute

interprete.value("a")#11
```

Comment: Hello @Rodrigo and welcome to StackOverflow, seems like it's your homework? Have you  tried something?

Comment: To you want to (have to) write a basic interpreter in Ruby or a basic Ruby interpreter (one that interprets Ruby)?

Comment: @Зелёный i dont know where to start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [binding](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Binding.html). It's a way to 'store' a scope in a variable that can be reopened at will using `eval`. This is a good tutorial, and what I used as reference to piece together a solution [Ruby’s Binding Class (binding objects)](https://codequizzes.wordpress.com/2014/05/18/rubys-binding-class-binding-objects/)
:

```
class Interprete
  def initialize
    @commands = []
    @binding = binding
  end
  def add(command)
    @commands.push command
  end
  def execute
    @commands.each { |command| @binding.eval command }
    @commands = []
  end
  def value(variable_name)
    @binding.eval variable_name
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
i = Interprete.new
i.add "a = 1"
i.execute
i.value "a" # => 1
```

A note about this: `binding` returns a new object each time it's called; that's why it's cached in the `@binding` instance variable. Without doing this, each command will be executed in a different scope and the results won't be accessible.

Comment: Thank you very much